# Random XML Exceptions - ' ', Hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml, hex

I'm getting random errors when trying to load to an XDocument, complaining about invalid characters in my XML.

```
' ', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
```

This happens with one of these 21 locations, but sometimes doesn't. It's the BBC's RSS, so it is strictly managed and encoded XML. When I open the files that I've downloaded and have a problem with, they sometimes look like this inside:

Í–ÛnÛ8†ïôhQ[¤¤ÈvÙÁÆEZ`“¢hÒä2 %Ú""‰IÅÍ[õúd;”åSì´nÐ,öÆ¦43üçð‘P|ò­Èáž+-d9t<—:ÀËD¦¢œ
¯WgÝs2zý*VZº–:bFC'3¦Š™Ïçî<p¥šŸÒüF§uœq‰Q[®‹Wûbé¬µ}ÔF%€8ÉXYò¼yÀG+å¢¼ƒLñéj?YñÒÍÅ=w'“ÄM¤[ß‘9g&ãŠL9O5á%ñ{Gƒ°L‚”=L¥â  ÓÆmtÏ‡ŽæùÔóPñ¡Ãª*   3˜AwX„d™„&ç£ÓÓ1Ü,4 gí†€;|È™žÉy¾–ÂðþÁ¦²ˆÉ"´ÝÇÖ1ÚèÈnîmÊ1i\Û°”ëD‰Ê&7
ºXL7Å[m˜*YÀF’e’×vš0_¾2¼¨¸b¦VX™Â\à(qŸ¢©>&›jË¼Y9«ÙŒ8ÚW­1‘Õƒ³ÌŒÆËUoÆoáT    #t†ÿ’¥6[›ÈXªJªFªšsØÛÃU¡ KSaY~kÁÑ™A\mÅ–)7Lä:&ëÚŒªzòž>ºÊêÐc¸ÀŽùÔÀëGÞ ÂÅ;êQ“¥c'ŠuYnê¸S­òåØµÁÚ[ªx4zê®OÒd¡‰Hd‰¿e*îEZcÂþíâ/oey›ÛŠo'3âùîLLcbEVŠÏ#
ç"5Ù¨ëÅd±Z2Þ´ØZÚeÛ5²Ù¶ûP<n!ÎAiÄ6‚s_˜Àá_ˆRuWk"#èÿø>†7GáïgowÚxpQ'(6¤KÛû—â¸±'ã½ÀyÛˆ>Ie2DA#œùCk¿¬ð²ÁÈ¢Ê:p-´˜ˆ\¬ôš«ø eÚÏŠkÝ÷ŠI>Ö…H¯>ýá¹†/BßEà£¯Ìóz¡wnÁº¬KÍñ<ù^äypzyµï|>yŒœÕ/ ýO;Ç~
)Ë5wjt—v­J—†]z|åõ"J#¿çŽ(ÊEVÏn¿!ÖÜûQ%EiFaèz¡B÷ÈõÃ~/ˆÉ–}Å×©½x)ÑÀu“¡Æ¹¬±éìÛî€½ ™pØLøÅô~
à/ó;à„ìBjñ„KY?Iªç†*Ââm³Úëm²ìeU  ±4Œpªë6¿Áÿ_o‹ßVË¥ô¿ä÷ÒNv÷zÜ] BŸ8\ðáý€ýßx3¿' ÞLp?À{¨
¦ÖtÃ~‡Ú`—ÚðYÔE¼µþµ­ÖKQ‹X«OòØ~ãÿëWÿÈ
U¢<

Is this corrupted? Am I having problems as these weather locations are updated? Here is my code...

Module_XML_Download:

```
 Public Sub DownloadXML(ByVal URL As String, ByVal SaveAs As String)
    Try
        Dim WebClient As New System.Net.WebClient()

        WebClient.DownloadFile(URL, SaveAs)
        If My.Settings.LogXMLDownloaded = True Then
            Module_Log.WriteLog(Now.ToString & "   XML Downloaded: " & SaveAs)
        End If

    Catch _Exception As Exception

        ' Error
        ' MsgBox("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString())
        If My.Settings.LogXMLDownloadError = True Then
            Module_Log.WriteLog(Now.ToString & "   XML DL Error: " & _Exception.Message)
        End If
    End Try

End Sub
```

And:

```
Public Sub DownloadWeather()

    If IsConnectionAvailable() = True Then

        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2657832/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Aberdeen.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2656752/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Aviemore.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2653609/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Barra.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2650752/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Dundee.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2650798/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Dumfries.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2651245/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Dingwall.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2650225/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Edinburgh.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2648579/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Glasgow.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2636239/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Harris.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2646088/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Inverness.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2655051/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Islay.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2636790/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Lewis.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2635754/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Mull.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2641108/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Oban.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2645198/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Orkney.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2640358/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Perth.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2644605/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Shetland.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2640006/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Skye.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2635881/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Thurso.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2643811/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Uist.xml")
        Module_XML_Download.DownloadXML("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2635199/3dayforecast.rss", My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Ullapool.xml")

    End If

End Sub
```

Then an example of one of my loading Subs:

```
Public Sub WeatherAviemore_Load()
    'weatherDoc = XDocument.Load("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2656752/3dayforecast.rss")
    weatherDoc = XDocument.Load(My.Settings.DataMainFolder & "\" & My.Settings.DataWeatherXMLFolder & "\Aviemore.xml")
    PopulateWeatherListBox(weatherDoc, MainForm.WeatherAviemoreListBox, "Aviemore", "An Aghaidh Mhòr")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample you are giving is not xml document and message says that your document is bad from very beginning (`Line 1, position 1`). A xml document should look like this ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<俄语>данные</俄语>
```

**Edit**
As I understand it now a file is sometimes downloaded correctly and sometimes doesn't. So the best solution is to accept the fact and attempt to download again. For example

```
    Dim Success As Boolean = False
    Do
        Try
            weatherDoc = XDocument.Load("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2656752/3dayforecast.rss")
            Success = True
        Catch ex As XmlException
            Success = False
        End Try
    Loop Until Success
```

And maybe ask another question something "Why I am sometimes downloading garbage from open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather?"

Comment: The RSS document looks like this:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" version="2.0">
  <channel>
   etc...

Comment: So when then exception doesn't occur the file look like you write here (<?xml etc...) and when problem occurs the file is like in question (Í–ÛnÛ8†ï etc ...)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. When I look at the files that are downloaded, the corrupt looking one is a quarter of the usual file size of a working downloaded file.

Comment: The links to the RSS are above in the Sub DownloadWeather.

Comment: Done, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480631/why-am-i-sometimes-downloading-garbage-data-from-bbc-weather-rss-feeds

Answer (score -1):

I have faced same issue and found the solution, maybe your feed uses GZip compression and you should decompress it.

My posted answer is here, unfortunately I have no knowledge about VB, you should try VB version of C# code.

[0x1F XML Error Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50796190/the-hexadecimal-value-0x1f-is-not-a-valid-character-line-1-item-1/52072831#52072831)

Have a nice day.